# Why I don't see the ID Token or Auth Token?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I followed the article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory and created an App role

I was thinking that Azure AD would return the IDToken however what I see is below, it does not look like a JWT token

[image]

What is this code? How does the Spring Boot decodes the code and understands the user role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this code?

This is the `authorization code`. Typically you would use this code to get access token and id token. If you are using Azure AD SDK like MSAL, the SDK will take care of getting tokens using the authorization code.

To learn more about authorization code flow, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow.

Comment: I am using spring boot, Looks like it is internally generating the tokens. is it possible to generate the token using the above generated code? How do I get the token using postman?

Comment: `How do I get the token using postman?` - Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redeem-a-code-for-an-access-token